# Conventions for querystring parameters

Tags: javascript, html, url, query-string

When I have a url like this:

```
http://server/site?firstname=Jack&lastname=Daniels
```

I understand that in my JavaScript a query for firstname should return "Jack".

But what should the query for firstname return in the following cases:

```
http://server/site?lastname=Daniels
http://server/site?firstname&lastname=Daniels
http://server/site?firstname=&lastname=Daniels
```

[Edit] To answer some of the comments: all of the above are legal querystrings, my question is not about how to retrieve the parameters but how to interpret them.

For the record, I parse querystrings with the following regular expression that covers all cases:

```
/([^?=&;]+)(?:=([^&;]*))?/g
```

Apparently there's [a very popular question on how to retrieve querystring parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/1048572), but the answer is incorrect (or at least not addressing edge cases).

[Update] My choice based on the answers from @Bergi and @zzzzBov:

```
http://server/site?lastname=Daniels                => firstname: undefined
http://server/site?firstname&lastname=Daniels      => firstname: true
http://server/site?firstname=&lastname=Daniels     => firstname: ""
http://server/site?firstname=Jack&lastname=Daniels => firstname: "Jack"
```

A side effect is that I had to slightly modify my regex, as with the above rules the `=` sign needs to be captured:

```
/([^?=&;]+)(=[^&;]*)?/g
```

Comment: Get the query string data and meanwhile you can ignore the not valid query string parameters and show result set with the valid parameters

Comment: Personally, I always this use function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what should the query return

That's your decision, what do you need? There are several querystring-evaluating functions of different complexity. Some of them can deal with repeated, nested, bracket-syntax values, others not. Famous ones can be found in [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/1048572) and its duplicate questions.

However, you asked for conventions:

> `http://server/site?lastname=Daniels`

The result should be something falsy to represent the absence of `firstName`. You might choose `null` or `undefined`.

> `http://server/site?firstname&lastname=Daniels`

This often represents some boolean parameter, so returning `true` would be legitimate. Yet I'm sure there are libs that completely ignore this format.

> `http://server/site?firstname=&lastname=Daniels`

That's quite obviously the empty string `""`.

Comment: Thx! I didn't think about returning true for the second case. Would you have a reference that shows it's standard?

Comment: Since none of these functions are standardized, there hardly will be a reference. Of course you might have a look at URL-parsing-functions' documentations in popular js libraries.

Comment: Marked this one as answer and I really like the idea of setting the parameter to true in case 2. However as I said in my updated post the reference doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

> But what should the query for firstname return in the following cases:
>
> ```
> http://server/site?lastname=Daniels
> http://server/site?firstname&lastname=Daniels
> http://server/site?firstname=&lastname=Daniels
> ```

Query strings can easily be represented by object notation in JavaScript. Simply set only the keys that are present in the query string on the object.

This means that for `?lastname=Daniels` the object produced should be:

```
{
    lastname: 'Daniels'
}
```

In cases where the key is present, but no value is given (no equals sign), the key should be set with a value of `null` which represents "no value".

This means that for `?firstname&lastname=Daniels` the object produced should be:

```
{
    firstname: null,
    lastname: 'Daniels'
}
```

In cases where the key is present, and the value provided is empty (equals sign), the value is actually the empty string.

This means that for `?firstname=&lastname=Daniels` the object produced should be:

```
{
    firstname: '',
    lastname: 'Daniels'
}
```

There is also an often overlooked case of where the same key is used multiple times. In the traditional query-string syntax (not PHP), keys can be used multiple times, as-is, to represent an array.

This means that for `?foo=bar&foo=baz` the object produced should be:

```
{
    foo: [
        'bar',
        'baz'
    ]
}
```

<aside>

In PHP land, keys used for arrays are suffixed with `[]`:

```
`?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz`
```

PHP will automatically convert the query-string server side such that:

```
$_GET['foo'] = array('bar', 'baz')
```

</aside>

Going back to the original question, what this implies is the following:

- `?lastname=Daniels` has a value of `undefined` for the `firstname` key.
- `?firstname&lastname=Daniels` has a value of `null` for the `firstname` key.
- `?firstname=&lastname=Daniels` has a value of `''` for the `firstname` key.

For cases where a key is used as a boolean based on its presence, you should be checking whether the object has the key set (and completely ignore the value, as it doesn't matter).

Typically this is done with `obj.hasOwnProperty('key')`, however as the object is really more of a hash, [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'key')` is preferrable](http://www.devthought.com/2012/01/18/an-object-is-not-a-hash/), which could be abstracted into a `has` function:

```
has(obj, key) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
}
```

If you're using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), then you could use [`_.has(obj, key)`](http://underscorejs.org/#has)

Comment: @Christophe, Bergi makes a good point about the use of boolean keys, however if you're using an object representation of a query-string you should be using `obj.hasOwnProperty('key')` to check if the key exists in the object. Actually, even that's wrong, [you should *really* be using something like `has(obj, 'key')`](http://www.devthought.com/2012/01/18/an-object-is-not-a-hash/).